# How do I define a variable and call it in a hidden input field?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a javascript code that does some math and I need to be able to just pull the final result and include it in a form. To do that I wanted to just use a `<input type="hidden" name="new total">`. I want to grab the results from the field "New Total". You can see my javascript code in action here. http://jsfiddle.net/danielrbuchanan/yjrTZ/5/

```
var prices = [];

function remove(arr,itm){
    var indx = arr.indexOf(itm);
    if (indx !== -1){
        arr.splice(indx,1);
    }
}

function calculateSectedDues(checkbox, amount) {
    if (checkbox.checked === true) {
        prices.push(amount);
    } else {
        remove(prices, amount);
    }

    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = prices.length; i < len; i++)
        total += prices[i];

    var min = prices.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a-b})[0];
    if(typeof min === 'undefined') min = 0;

    var withDiscount = total - min;
    var discountAmount = withDiscount - total;

    //document.grad_enroll_form.total.value = total;
    document.querySelector("#value").innerHTML = "Total: $"+total+'<br>';
    document.querySelector("#value").innerHTML += "Discount: $"+discountAmount+'<br>';
    document.querySelector("#value").innerHTML += "New total: $"+withDiscount+'<br>';
}
```

It seems simple, for some reason I'm drawing a blank on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i think you want is to set an input value with your variable, so i think it should go like this:

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("newTotal").value = your_new_total;
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id='newTotal' type='hidden' name='NewTotal' value='' />
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to change the value hidden to test it to visually see that it is grabbing the total?

Comment: Yes... change the type to text. Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yjrTZ/7/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" id="new_total" name="new_total">
<!-- no spaces in name and id -->
```

Put this code at end of the `calculateSectedDues` function

`document.getElementById('new_total').value = withDiscount`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

**Option 1:**
jQuery

Add a visible div, how ever you want to do things.
Bind onChange() events to your input fields that drive the calculation.

```
<div id="finalValue"></div>

<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $("form input").change(function() {
        calculateSectedDues($("#checkboxid"), $("#amountid").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

In the calculateSectedDues() function add this to the end:

```
$("#finalValue").html("Total: $" + total + "<br />Discount: " + discountAmount + "<br />New Total: " + withDiscount + "<br />");
```

**Option 2:**
No jQuery

```
<div id="finalValue"></div>

<script language="javascript">
function bindEvent() {
    calculateSectedDues(document.getElementById("checkboxid"), document.getElementById("amountid").value);
}
window.onload = function()
{
    var elJ = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0;i<elJ.length;i++) {
        elJ[i].addEventListener('change',bindEvent,false);
    }
}
</script>
```

In the calculateSectedDues() function add this to the end:

```
document.getElementById("finalValue").InnerHtml("Total: $" + total + "<br />Discount: " + discountAmount + "<br />New Total: " + withDiscount + "<br />");
```

Is that what you are trying to get after?

You should also remember to do the calculation on the Server Side too and not rely on the JavaScript to do it for you. This would simply be to notify the user what they are getting before hand. Otherwise, front-end hacks could easily be done if you are using a hidden total field.